# What does the "c." listed under weapon length mean?

Tags: weapons, adnd-1e

In the PHB, some weapons have a length that begins with "c" and some others don't:

| Weapon Type | Length |
| --- | --- |
| Arrow | — |
| Axe, Battle | c. 4' |
| Axe, Hand or throwing | c. 1 ½' |
| Bardiche | c. 5' |
| Bec de corbin | c. 6' |
| Bill-Guisarme | 8'+ |
| Bo Stick | c. 5' |
| Club | c. 3' |
| Dagger | c. 15" |
| Dart | — |
| Fauchard | 8'+ |
| Fauchard-Fork | 8' |

([image of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZB85S.png))

What does "c" mean in this context?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the use of *c.* in the Weapon Types, General Data, and "To Hit" Adjustments table isn't defined anywhere in the *Player's Handbook* (1978).

However, I've always taken that *c.* to mean [*circa*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circa). While usually employed in conjunction with estimating historical dates, using *circa* to mean *“approximately”* isn't unheard of, and Gygax seems to be doing that here.

For example, this would mean that the *c. 4'* entry for the battle axe's length means that a battle axe is about 4 feet long.

Comment: Following the link the OP provided, commenter Jason agrees with you, "I believe c. Stands for the Latin word “circa” which means “about” "

Comment: @ExcessOperatorHeadspace Good to hear! (As I am wary of Wordpress links, I instead refreshed my memory of the table by going over to my bookshelf. `:-)`)

Comment: @HeyICanChan Digginging into my vagure memory of style guides from back than, I think you nailed it.  But I don't have that one anymore on the book shelf.  Might be worth an ask at English . SE.

Comment: You are correct in your assumption...it's basically saying that the weapon is usually about that size, though there might be variations in length plus or  minus

Comment: (I am now curious if Gygax's research really yielded the fact (?) that a fouchard-fork is always *exactly* 8 ft. long.)